# Error in notification.alert

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a Cordova project.
It was working all fine but. Just few hours ago I started getting error notification.alert
Although I haven't changed the code.
And it was working all fine earlier.

Comment: Could you please *elaborate* more. Post some of your *code* with *events* which you have used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure **'deviceready'** event should fire before calling any api or plugin, if you call before **'deviceready'** event fires, the libraries are not yet loaded into the application so it will give error. Cross check these things if problem not solved, post your code to find the error.